# Append a data in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, append

In javaScript i try to append a data it work but in data url id and close button not working

```js
success: function(response)
{
    $.each(response, function () {
        $.each(this, function (index, value) {
            $('#List').append('' +
                '<div class="col-md-12"><div  class="alert @if('+value.linkValue+' == 0)alert-danger @else alert-success @endif">'+ value.item +
                '<button data-id='+value.id+' data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-url="{{ route("list.delete", '+value.id+') }}" type="button" class="close cls-btn" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">times;</span></button>'+
                '</div>'+
                '</div>'
            );
        });
    });
},
```

the above code `data-url="{{ route("list.delete", '+value.id+') }}"` `show data-url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/delete/+value.id+"` and `<span aria-hidden="true">times;</span></button>`show `times;`
how to add value in data-url and close button in appending time?

Comment: because when you append new doms, the already established event listener would not be triggered by them. Or more precisely, they dont have the event listener attached to them since they are new doms. Change the event listener to target a parent dom like `#list`.

Comment: @N69S Button is working and data looping correctly data-url is problem